# Trigger.IO topbar Adding 2 buttons with right position next to each another

Tags: javascript, trigger.io

I'm currenly developing a trigger.io app and im trying to put at the topbar 2 buttons at the right of the topbar.

Here is the main idea of what i'm looking to do.
Where "1" and "2" are the button I want.

```
+-------------------------+---+---+
|             TITLE       | 1 | 2 |
+-------------------------+---+---+
```

I'm trying to add 2 buttons but, they continuously put them one left and one right.
Is there a way to put them next to each other by the JS or I have to put them together by CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a limitation in the Trigger.io topbar module - there's the `position` parameter you can pass into `addButton` which affects the alignment of a single button, but we don't support that for multiple buttons yet.

I've added it to our backlog - it's definitely something we aim to support in a future platform version!